# Enhanced for-loops and float arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, floating-point

One of my homework assignments was to write a small *enhanced* for-loop with floats. I understand the basis of this loop style with integer arrays, to my understanding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < some.number; i++)
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i : array_example)
```

If this is accurate how is this supposed to work with a array filled with floats? I thought the incremental operator (`i++`) was only allowable with integers. Just looking for some clarification.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here's an example of what I'm doing, and what Eclipse doesn't like. Which is probably adding to my confusion:

```
public class java_array 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float[] values = {1/2,1/3,5/3};
        float total = 0;
        for (float i : values)
        {
            values[i] = i; //Getting an error here "can't convert from float to int.
        }
        for (float i : values)
        {
            System.out.println(values[i]);  //Getting an error here "can't convert from float to int.
        }
    }   
}
```

Everything has been declared as `float`. Why is the IDE saying this?

Comment: the last part of the for loop is just an instruction that will be executed after each iteration. You could even put a `System.out.println()` there, it doesn't have to be `i++`

Comment: Does that apply to the enhanced loop as well?

Comment: The first for loop is simply a range, the second iterates through a collection. In this case, you are saying that array_example is of type int.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) is relevant

Comment: regarding that last edit you made, you can only access an array with an `int` (the position in the array) i.e. you are calling `values[i]` when `i` is a float, that will never work

Comment: `(float value : values)` where `value` will be `1/2` on the first iteration, `1/3` on the second, etc... No need to have an array index.

Comment: You just need `System.out.println(i);`. You also need to divide by a float to get a float. dividing by two `ints` gets you an `int`. `1/2` should be `1/2.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enhanced for loop, returns the *values* in the array, not the *indices*.

In the integer case, if `myArray = [2,4,6,8];`

```
for (int i : myArray)
   // returns 2,4,6,8,  NOT 0,1,2,3
```

In a traditional loop, you have an extra step

```
for (int idx = 0; idx<myArray.length; i++) {
  // idx will be 0,1,2,3
  int value = myArray[i];  <<< in many cases this is an extra step
  // value will be 2,4,6,8
}
```

Now, if you need *both* the index and the value for some reason, you need the old fashioned loop.

So, for an old fashioned loop over a floatArray, you need an int for the index and a float for the value.  If floatArray = [2.2, 4.4, 6.6, 8.8]

```
   for (int idx = 0; idx<floatArray .length; i++) {
      // idx will be 0,1,2,3
      float value = floatArray [i];
      // value will be 2.2, 4.4, 6.6, 8.8
    }
```

with the enhanced for loop, you just need a float

```
  for (float value : floatArray ) {
     // value will be 2.2, 4.4, 6.6, 8.8
```

Comment: That makes sense, but what if I needed to start off at index[1] rather than the first (index[0])? Is that possible with the enhanced loop?

Comment: @Matt, you can always create another array based off your first, but only provide elements to the new array that you need, e.g. `array[1:n]`. Then use the enhanced for-loop for the new array.

Comment: You can do fancy things like @bblincoe suggests.  Or have some boolean or counter to skip over a few at the start.  But, IMO, it's often simplest in the tricky cases to use the old fashioned loop.

Comment: @user949300 agreed. I was just assuming he had to use the enhanced version.

Answer (score 3):

The enhanced for-loop is "syntactic sugar" for a standard for-loop. You can read more about the enhanced for-loop here: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

The following would work (assuming values is a float array):

```
for (float value : values)
{
    // value contains the iteration's float value. e.g.
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

When using the enhanced for-loop, there is no need to use an index to iterate through the items in the array.

Comment: Actually, an iterator is _not_ used when using the enhanced `for` loop with an array. It uses an index.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop contains three parts:

1. **Initialization**: You initalize the value. Could also be empty.
2. A **Condition**: The loop will iterate as long as this condition is true.
3. An **instruction** that is executed after each iteration, which is not necessarily `i++`

Your second for loop is actually a foreach. What it does is, it iterates through all Elements in the array and return them to you. The objects inside your array don't matter, it can be int, float, Object, whatever.

For example:

```
Object [] objects = new Object[100];
for (Object o : objects) {
  // will go through all 100 elements, returning them one after the other as o
}

float [] floats = new float[100];
for (float f : floats) {
  // will go through all 100 elements as well, returning them as f
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two for loops aren't exactly equivalent. The first for loop is in fact mostly similar to a while loop.

```
    for(init; condition; post) {
       ... code
    }
```

Is similar to:

```
    init;
    while(condition) {
        ... code
        post;
    }
```

If you go deeper, you'll realize that most syntax can be rewritten using gotos. It's just syntastic sugar to make it "less" prone to errors.

The other form is using an iterator. This for form is able to get an iterator from an object such as arrays. The can be implemented on other objects. That said, there is 2 problems in your code.

```
    for (float i : values)
    {
        values[i] = i; //Getting an error here "can't convert from float to int.
    }
```

When you're iterating over values, you cannot set `values[i]` to something because `i` is of type float. Indexes for arrays are usualy ints, because you cannot access an object in between two objects.

The second less obvious problem is that you're changing the value of values within a for loop. There are chances that the code above will work but you have to understand that an iterator isn't simply a way to iterate over objects in a list.

As far as I remember, if you had some kind of concurency. Editing the values pointed by an iterator might invalidate the iterator. It will raise an exception because you could be iterating over invalid data. The iterator pattern usually force to raise an exception and restart the for loop if possible. If you change the data within the for loop it could raise such kind of exception.

Answer (score 1):

The type changes

```
for (float i : array_example)
```

underneath an iterator has an index which count to integer and has that type.

in the EDIT code `values[i]` is erroneous because `i` is float an can't be an index. IDE is your choice it complains before the compilation time because it is capable to catch errors like that. You should trust it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i : array_example)
```

Reads like this.  For each `int` in int array `array_example`, do something with that `int`. the `i` is just a random variable you use to `access` that `int`. `i` can be any variable. You can call it `turkey` if you want.

```
int[] array_example = {1, 2, 3};
for (int turkey : array_example){    // for each int in array_example
    System.out.print(turkey + ", "); // print out that int
}

output: 1, 2, 3
```

For `float`

```
float[] floatArray = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4};
for (float watermelon : floatArray){
    System.out.print(watermelon + ", ");
}

output: 1.2, 2.3, 3.4
```

**Edit: after OP edit**

You just need `System.out.println(i);`. The other error is because you're trying to use the `float i` as an index. an index needs to be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply enhanced `for-each` loop to any array or any object that implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

It is a [short-cut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for a loop with [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Java [`Collections`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm) satisfy the criteria and can be used with for-each loops.

In your particular case (array of floats) you will have something like this:

```
float[] fArray = {1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 23F, 24F};
for (float element: fArray) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Please note that `element` is a copy of an actual array element and if you assign a value to it directly, it will have no impact on the array itself.